# How to load configuration after login in symfony

Tags: database, symfony, config

I have a Symfony 3.4 app that could contain multiple companies.
Each company have their own config, and their own data in db, so I need that each company have their own db.
When any user login, The application has a "core database" containing user's info.
After user login  the application must change configuration for connect to user company database, that had saved in "core database".

There are necessary steps:

- One user enter his user and password
- the app look into central db and get user's authentication.
- The app get user configuration to change.
- The app change the configuration and now, sql request will be to the company's db.

It is possible? If not, is there any alternative?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to [work here with multiple entity managers and connections](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html) and and idea is to use a subscriber that retrieves the current customer based on the user. This subscriber (or another service) will set a global variable containing the name of the entity manager.

```
// A subscriber (high level priority) or a service already set $customerName

// In your controller or in a service
$customerEntityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager($customerName);
```

Check also this bundle for ideas https://github.com/vmeretail/multi-tenancy-bundle

**Edit**

Use and adapt to your needs this file https://github.com/vmeretail/multi-tenancy-bundle/blob/master/Service/TenantResolver.php

Here you just need to resolve tenant from the current User.

In your controller:

```
...

public function index(TenantResolver $tenantResolver)
{
    $customerEntityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager($tenantResolver->getTenant()->getName()); // or getId() or something else
}
```

In a service:

```
...

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

private $tenantResolver;
private $managerRegistry;

public function__construct(TenantResolver $tenantResolver, ManagerRegistry $managerRegistry)
{
    $this->tenantResolver = $tenantResolver;
    $this->managerRegistry = $managerRegistry;
}

public function doSomething()
{
    $this->managerRegistry->getManager($this->tenantResolver->getTenant()->getName());  // or getId() or something else
}
```

It's the idea, there must be something better to do here like injecting directly the right manager in the service/controller constructor.

Comment: If you could provide a small working example(Like @FrankB says) it could be awesome! I've read about that and I think that's nice solution

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution for Symfony 4 and i think it should work for symfony 3.4 as well.

I created a service that copies the default entity manager in a new one connecting to another database:

```
namespace App\Service;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class CustomEntityManagerHelper 
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->em = $entityManager;
    }

    /*
     * get entity manager for another database
     */
    public function getManagerForDatabase($db_name): EntityManagerInterface
    {
        $conn = array(
            'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
            'user' => 'root',
            'password' => 'mypass',
            'dbname' => $db_name
        );

        return \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create(
            $conn,
            $this->em->getConfiguration(),
            $this->em->getEventManager()
        );
    }
}
```

Until now it was very easy but the Repository class still uses the default entitymanager. So i added a method setEntityManager to the Repositories:

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\Product;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class ProductRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Product::class);
    }

    public function setEntityManager(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): self
    {
        $this->_em = $entityManager;

        return $this;
    }

    // custom methods here
}
```

Now i can use the custom entity manager AND set that to the repository:

```
use App\Service\CustomEntityManagerHelper;

// ...

/**
 * @Route("/products", name="app_product", methods={"GET"})
 */
public function index(CustomEntityManagerHelper $helper): Response
{
    $myManager = $helper->getManagerForDatabase($this->getUser()->getDatabaseName());

    $products = $myManager->getRepository('App:Product')
        ->setEntityManager($myManager)                  // IMPORTANT!
        ->findAll();

    return $this->render('product/index.html.twig', [
        'products' => $products
    ]);
}
```

Comment: it seem too complex if we compare with @qdequippe solution. Seems the same result but more complex implementation. 
I'm wrong?

Comment: actually it is not so complex i think but what i dont like is that you have to add a setEntityManager method to each Repository class that you want to use for the custommer's database, even if you use a base class for it. It would be nicer when $myManager->getRepository('App:Product') would set the repository with the right entity manager.